# Can't write to a file that I own and is marked as writeable?

Tags: linux, debian, file-permissions

I am working on Debian Jessie. As user `opuser` I have created a file and I own it:

```
opuser@mymachine: $ ls -lash /webapps/myapp/run/gunicorn.sock
0 srwxrwxrwx 1 opuser webapps 0 Sep  1 18:50 /webapps/myapp/run/gunicorn.sock
```

Now if I try to open the file to write to it:

```
opuser@mymachine: $ vi /webapps/myapp/run/gunicorn.sock
```

`vi` shows an error at the bottom: `"~/run/gunicorn.sock" [Permission Denied]`.

Why can't I open a file to write to it when I own it, and the file permissions show that it is world-writeable?

UPDATED:

The file was created by running gunicorn, and the reason I'm debugging this is that the gunicorn user can't write to it either:

```
gunicorn openprescribing.wsgi:application --name myapp_prod --workers 3 --bind=unix:/webapps/webapps/run/gunicorn.sock --user opuser --group webapps --log-level=debug
```

Here's the full error:

```
[2015-09-01 11:18:36 +0000] [9439] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  proxy_protocol: False
  worker_connections: 1000
  statsd_host: None
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  post_fork: <function post_fork at 0x7efebefd2230>
  pythonpath: None
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  worker_class: sync
  ssl_version: 3
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  syslog: False
  syslog_facility: user
  when_ready: <function when_ready at 0x7efebefc6ed8>
  pre_fork: <function pre_fork at 0x7efebefd20c8>
  cert_reqs: 0
  preload_app: False
  keepalive: 2
  accesslog: None
  group: 999
  graceful_timeout: 30
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  spew: False
  workers: 3
  proc_name: myapp_prod
  sendfile: True
  pidfile: None
  umask: 0
  on_reload: <function on_reload at 0x7efebefc6d70>
  pre_exec: <function pre_exec at 0x7efebefd27d0>
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  post_worker_init: <function post_worker_init at 0x7efebefd2398>
  limit_request_fields: 100
  on_exit: <function on_exit at 0x7efebefd2e60>
  config: None
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  pre_request: <function pre_request at 0x7efebefd2938>
  post_request: <function post_request at 0x7efebefd2a28>
  user: 999
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  worker_int: <function worker_int at 0x7efebefd2500>
  threads: 1
  max_requests: 0
  limit_request_line: 4094
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  certfile: None
  worker_exit: <function worker_exit at 0x7efebefd2b90>
  chdir: /webapps/myapp/myapp
  paste: None
  default_proc_name: myapp.wsgi:application
  errorlog: -
  loglevel: debug
  logconfig: None
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  syslog_prefix: None
  daemon: False
  ciphers: TLSv1
  on_starting: <function on_starting at 0x7efebefc6c08>
  worker_abort: <function worker_abort at 0x7efebefd2668>
  bind: ['unix:/webapps/myapp/run/gunicorn.sock']
  raw_env: []
  reload: False
  check_config: False
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  nworkers_changed: <function nworkers_changed at 0x7efebefd2cf8>
  timeout: 30
  ca_certs: None
  django_settings: None
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  keyfile: None
  backlog: 2048
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  statsd_prefix:
[2015-09-01 11:18:36 +0000] [9439] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anna/.virtualenvs/myapp/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/home/anna/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/home/anna/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 189, in run
    super(Application, self).run()
  File "/home/anna/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/home/anna/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 171, in run
    self.start()
  File "/home/anna/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 130, in start
    self.LISTENERS = create_sockets(self.cfg, self.log)
  File "/home/anna/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 211, in create_sockets
    sock = sock_type(addr, conf, log)
  File "/home/anna/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 104, in __init__
    os.remove(addr)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/webapps/myapp/run/gunicorn.sock'
```

Comment: You do realize that you have two different paths there?

Comment: sorry, that's just a typo! edited.

Comment: And the users home directory really is `/webapps/myapp`?

Comment: @arkascha yes - `$ eval echo ~$opuser` produces `/webapps/myapp`.

Comment: @Richard : is it normal that gunicorn.sock is a socket ? Who create it ?

Comment: @Garf365 updated question to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The node you are trying to open is a socket.  More preciselly a unix domain socket  (the `s` in the permissions flags signals this).  Sockets are not `open(2)`ed the normal way (that's the reason `vi(1)` fails.)  They have to be acquired with the `socket(PF_UNIX, ...)` system call (see `unix(7)`) and then `bind(2)`ed to a proper path in the filesystem (this is what makes them to appear in the filesystem's hierarchy).

Once you have got a socket of this kind working, you have to `connect(2)` it to another socket (or to `accept(2)` as it has been bound to a filesystem node) to allow communications flow from one socket to the other.

For an introduction to sockets api programming (and UNIX domain sockets) read the famous R.W.Stevens book *Unix Network Programming, Volume 1: The Sockets Networking API (3rd Edition)*.

Answer (score 1):

Your file type is a socket. It is read once / write once. Not sure you can open that with a regular text editor.

Comment: Thanks, that explains why I can't open it in vi. The reason I'm trying is that the gunicorn user can't write to it either - see updated question. Any idea how I can debug what's going on with gunicorn?